# Logic for Rock Paper Scissors is not working in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

It is supposed to show 3 buttons(rock, paper or scissors) and the computer will generate a random choice. It will show the results. A simple game and it worked perfectly when it was a class-based component but when I converted it to a functional one with hooks instead of state, it bugged and showed the winner wrong compared to what the user and computer show that they picked. When you console.log it, it shows what should be coming up but the screen shows something else. I've tried different ways to do the logic such as switch case statements and if statements but none seemed to work.

```
        const [RPSc, setRPSc] = useState(['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'])
        const [RPSu, setRPSu] = useState(null)
        const [randomNum, setrandomNum] = useState(null)
        const [outcome, setOutcome] = useState('')
        const [RPSca, setRPSca] = useState(null)

    function handleClick(type) {
        const min = 0;
        const max = 3;
        setRPSu(type)
        setrandomNum(Math.floor(min + (Math.random() * (max - min))))
        setRPSca(RPSc[randomNum])
        setOutcome(
            <h1>{
                ((RPSu === 'Rock') && (RPSca === 'Scissors')) ||
                    ((RPSu === 'Paper') && (RPSca === "Rock")) ||
                    ((RPSu === 'Scissors') && (RPSca === "Paper")) ? 'You win' :
                    (RPSc[randomNum] === RPSu) ? "It's a tie" : 'The computer wins'
            }{console.log(RPSu + RPSca + randomNum)}</h1>
        )
    }
    return (
            <div>
                <button value="Click me!" onClick={() => handleClick('Rock')}>Rock</button>
                <button value="Click me!" onClick={() => handleClick('Paper')}>Paper</button>
                <button value="Click me!" onClick={() => handleClick('Scissors')}>Scissors</button>

                <h2 className="x">You selected: {RPSu}</h2>
                <h1 className='x'>The computer selected: {RPSca}</h1>

                {outcome}
            </div>
        );
```

Comment: Should your `outcome` be a contant?

Comment: setState calls are async; there's no need to store the random number in the component state though, just use a variable instead: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-firefly-z6nmd